# Fluent Nhibernate Get object with filled child collection

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have

```
public class Parents {
    public Parents() {
        Childs = new HashedSet<Childs>();
    }
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual String Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ISet<Childs> Childs {get; protected set;} 
}

public class Childs {
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual String Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Parents Parent {get; set;}
}
```

Mapping

```
....
.Override<Parents>(map => {
    map.HasMany(x => x.Childs).KeyColumn("parent_id").Cascade.SaveUpdate().Not.LazyLoad().AsSet().Fetch().Join();
})
 .Override<Childs>(map => {
      map.References(x => x.Parent, "parent_id");
})
....
```

How can i get(select) parent with childs using Link, HQL or AutoMapper? For example I have query like this in my test case,

```
Parents parent = new Parents {Name = "parent test"};
Childs child   = new Childs {Name = "child test", Parent = parent};
session.Save(parent);
session.Save(child);
...
var myParent = session.QueryOver<Parents>().Where(x=>x.Id==1).List()[0];
Assert.IsTrue(myParent.Childs.Count>0);
...
```

in log i see query: select with join, but i get only parent without childs

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the "Childs" property inverse.

When it is inverse, it is not stored. In you test case, the list is empty (you don't add the children to the parent, you only set the back-reference in the children to the parent). If it is stored, what it is doing now, NH clears the list in the database and removes the children from the parent.

Comment: I got it.  It happened due to a session. I need to read docs about using session. But could you provide link where I can read about it:" If it is stored, what it is doing now, NH clears the list in the database and removes the children from the parent" or maybe part of code NH, because i checked it and it is not true